# cannot enable bin-logs for mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I have an old 5.7 mysql database that crashed last week. But i was able to start it again.

Now we have an issue where certain settings are disabled but were or are still enabled in my.cnf.

The setting are log-bin and errors logs.

No logs were logged  or bin-logs were generated since last week when mysql crashed.

Enabling this on my.cnf does not have any difference.  Restarted mysql multi times and still does not enable bin-log.

```
Show variables like "bin-log";
```

Is off.

On the config file i have the following

```
log-error=/var/datadir/mysqld.log
server_id               = 1
log-bin                 = /var/datadir/mysql-bin.log
binlog_format           = row
```

But both error-log and bin-log are not working.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Tried to recreate the my.cnf config from another mysql server and just change the ip address. And still bin log is not enabled

Comment: It is customary to consistently use underscores rather than hyphens when naming Global Variables in MySQL.  Also many people have a /var/logs folder created and enabled to keep logs OUT of the /var/datadir world.  datadir was planned to be used for table storage, not logs.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqld` has a search path to load the my.cnf in a certain order, please make sure you know this point.

Comment: Hi we only have my.cnf file on the server. And if i make a typo on the file. mysql show errors